# Fixed element Y position calculated wrong after scroll on chrome for android

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, mobile

Happens when address bar becomes hidden/visible.

[image]

The element marked on the DOM explorer is the same element shown on the bottom of the screen (with the "Start Planning" button). After scroll it's actual location is being scrolled up (even though it is in fixed position), but no re-rendering occurs since it is still displayed on the screen in the correct position.

The interesting thing is that the element does not respond to clicks in the displayed area but rather in the DOM calculated area (aka, if you click above the button it works but not when you click on the button itself).

Here is the link the page on our platform that has the issue:

https://in-office.wekudo.com/wellness/category/nutrition/smoothie-bar

Same issue exists also on Airbnb's platform:

https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/select/17017021?search_id=74b85b09-c47b-4d33-854a-c42ffa1d7779&federated_search_id=93685a2b-81cc-49a4-9699-2e6adb1c1a25

Comment: post some code (in codepen for eg.) where one can inspect what's causing the bug and find a solution or at the very least, add a link to the demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug seems to be related to hammer.js:

https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1171

Answer (score 2):

In CSS, please add `overflow-y: visible !important;`

Comment: I assume you mean to add it to the parent. I didn't think it would work but tried it anyway (also tried adding it directly to the footer). May I ask why you think it's the solution?

Comment: I thought that it would be the solution because of the scrolling.

Comment: Can you please try adding position: static;

Comment: To which element?

Comment: The parent would be the one.

Comment: This could work, but `!important` just isn't sustainable. It's a quick fix, and it will confuse you or another front end developer who takes over. The "cascading" part of cascading style sheets has to be preserved for sustainable code. Hacking helps now, but it can delay development in the future: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/.